# Convert a String into a Number with Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to convert this type of amount `$ 105 000,00` in a number in Google Sheet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""),"$", ""),",00", ""))
```